# Creating a grid layout 3 columns, 1 item spans entire height of 1st column

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to offset 1 columns contents in CSS. I thought would be as simple as doing the following. Now this does offset the top but it makes the second column match the height of the first inclusive of the margin. How else can I offset the first column?

https://jsbin.com/delobaluga/edit?html,css,output

[image]

```
.grid {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
   grid-gap: 20px;
}

.grid .item:first-child {
   margin-top: 105px;
}

<div class='grid'>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please revise to put some HTML in a snippet demo using the editor. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If you want to offset the first column while keeping the height of the second column unaffected, you can use padding instead of margin on the first column. Padding affects the element's content area, while margin affects the surrounding area, so if you add padding to the first column, it will increase its size and offset the content inside it, but won't affect the height of the second column.

Here your code with this improvement:

```
.grid {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
   grid-gap: 20px;
}

.grid .item:first-child {
   padding-top: 105px;
}

<div class='grid'>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
</div>
```